# Validity of Log-rank p-value when there are zero events in one group?

Tags: kaplan-meier, logrank-test

I am looking to do a Kaplan Meier analysis to look at survival in two groups. I have 21 people in group A and 17 people in group B. 5 people in group B died at various times, 0 people in group A died, ie all my data is censored for Group A.

I am getting a log-rank p-value of 0.028 when I do the KM analysis. My question is can I still use the KM for survival analysis given the absence of events in one group and if so, is the p-value valid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the log rank test in that case.  The log rank test is something called a "score test" (I'm getting technical here), which remains valid under those conditions; however under ideal circumstances, score tests are often less powerful than likelihood ratio tests.